# Java: pass a different value to grandparent constructor

Tags: java

I'm working on a library which is based on another library Lib, which is based on an SDK.

I need to have my class `MyClass` extend a class from Lib `LibClass`, which in turn extends a class from SDK `SdkClass`. In the constructor of `LibClass`, it passes a value to `SdkClass`' constructor via `super(someArg)`.

However, for my code to work, I need to pass a different argument to SdkClass while keeping the rest the same. I don't have access to the source code of Lib. Is it possible to do it with some reflection?

Thank you!

Comment: An [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? I suggest that you will want to describe why you think you need this?

Comment: Maybe you could do it by using bytecode engineering to *inject* a new constructor into the parent class.  But that's modifying the class.  AFAIK there's no way to do it without modifying the parent class.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the suggestion. There is a method in `Unsafe` to allocate the object without calling the constructor. But I don't know how to invoke constructors later with the desired argument. Not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: It isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

While you ask a great question, unfortunately, what you want is not possible with reflection and plain-old Java in general. It breaks encapsulation, the same reason `super.super.method()` is not permitted in Java. The design you describe is clearly something like:

```java
// SdkClass
public class Shape {
  public Shape(boolean isRectangle) {}
}

// LibClass
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
  public Rectangle() {
    super(true);
  }
}

// MyClass
public class Square extends Rectangle {
  public Square() {
    super();
  }
}
```

The point is that `Rectangle` is designed to be a base class for all rectangular shapes.

Although, if your application is containerized through some framework such as Spring, you could potentially leverage AOP to accomplish this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html.